# c# getting a configurable equatable method

Tags: c#, .net, equality, predicate, iequalitycomparer

I've got a simple factory that's built in C# that instantiates and configures validators that are built in ASP.net and JavaScript. I want a way to test if I'm accidently trying to set a validator twice (for example, having two `RequiredValueValidator`s is not a great idea and could cause ui/ux problems) on the same Control, but I also wish to make sure that validators that use the same same building mechanisms, but in a different way, are preserved (such as two `RegularExpressionValidator`s that use different RE, but *not* two that use the same RE.)

I've tried a few different possible techniques that I'll detail these as answers below- but in essence I need a technique to pass a description on how to compare two validators of the same base type to discern if they are equal( **N.B. 'equal' is NOT 'identical'**, they could have different IDs (etc) but still do the same job.) that's interpretable at runtime and accessible to other areas of my c# .dll to actually run the check.

My answers will be community wiki with the intent that errors/pitfalls that I fell into will be edited out/corrected/discussed by the community, *rather than being merely downvoted for being initially incorrect*, so that others' won't suffer the same fate.

Comment: Why can't you use Equals() to compare? Probably I don't understand your problem correctly

Comment: I don't have visibility on the base classes.

Answer (score 0):

One attempt I've had is to set a predicate as an attribute of the method in my factory that builds the validator. This would then be accessed by using reflection somewhere else and then used to compare two potential validators.

A major flaw in this is that you cannot set predicates (or delegates for that matter) as attributes.

[A possible work-around](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcsharp2008prerelease/thread/0d18c410-07b0-41cc-9c7f-9494633ca101/) is where you give a an individual property (containing the predicate delegate or `IEquatable<>` implementation and then retrieve that - however there are a lot of different things to consider when comparing validators (what type, configurations, does it rely on other controls etc....) so unless you can create a base class or interface that can deal with different types of `IEquatable<ValidatorType>` this is also impossible...

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried creating a small, static switch case method within my factory that will be able to simply output another small configurations class that would be created by the switch case. This in essence is much simpler than the previous question, but it's not without it's problems. For example, I cannot define my return and parameter types correctly so that a `RegularExpressionValidator` can check if it's correct within the same code block as a `ValidDateValidator`check.